# Web Hosting Bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

The company that hosts my web servers mentions a **2mb/s** dedicated bandwidth with a burst of up to **5mb/s** using the 95th percentile ( Burstable ) billing.  To me that sounds slow but I know nothing about web hosting.  The only thing I can relate to is my residential service which is 25mb/s down and 25mb/s up.  Is this the same concept?

The reason this has come into question is because my web servers seem sluggish at times.  I checked the swap, MySQL process list and Apache service but nothing seems out of the ordinary.

I run MySQL Replication **Master** to **Slave** and am curious if the binlog transfer is eating up a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: I would expect your replication to be internal traffic and not subject to the 2mb/s limitations. 5mb is only 625 KB/sec, which is going to feel slow if more than a couple people are on at once.

Comment: Burstable billing is explained in details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstable_billing If you're curious about bandwidth usage, use some tools to capture traffic and analyze OR check if the log files will give you a clue.

Comment: Slave server is actually hosted internally at my office but the Master is hosted on the cloud through an outside company offsite

Comment: Why don't you go for hosting services with unlimited bandwidth? Check out hosts providing this feature.

Comment: The answer to whether that bandwidth is adequate can mostly be found in your webserver logs, although more sophisticated monitoring software does help. The question of why your website is unexpectedly slow would take a couple of weks of investigation and testing - a post here with no possible candidates isn't going to help.